# Laravel 5: best way to modify column name in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is the best way to modify column name before retrieve data from the model, ex: change `id` to be `uid`

```
$data = user::all(); //return array('uid'=>1,'uid'=>2 ... etc)
```

thanks,

Comment: Are you talking about permanently modifying the database schema, or just the model data structure for use in the view?

Comment: Modify column name on runtime, not permanent in DB,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest option would be to create a custom attribute getter. This will allow you to access the `uid` value, like you would any other attribute, and the value will also be accessible via the `toArray()` method.

```
class User extends Model
{
    // ...

    public $appends = [
        'uid',
    ];


    public function getUidAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['id'];
    }

    // ...
}

$user->uid; // 1
$user->toArray() // [..., 'uid' => 1, ...];
```

Comment: How to use it with `user::all()`, It retrieves array of rows? Can I modify it without  call `$user->uid`? just print `$data`

Comment: `User::all()` will return a collection of `User` model instances, so each will have access to `$user->uid`.

Comment: yes, but I want to return this collection of info as JSON, without loop inside them to call `$user->uid`, (or print all of them)

Comment: If you look at the Laravel source code, you will see that calling `$users->toJson()` internally uses the `toArray()` function, so it will do as you require.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to include this information in your original question.

Comment: I think he did include that information in his original question, at least I don't see any indication of edits. He clearly showed he is looking to have "user::all();" return the data with the modified column name.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, I'd like to add: This is a great answer! 

Comment: @Air - `User:all()` will return an array of `User` models, not an array of arrays. This was where the confusion came from. The requirement for calling `toJson()` was only mentioned in the comments.